# What does "unified" windows 10 mean for malware/vulnerabilities?

Tags: windows-10, security, malware, vulnerabilities

If I understand the new windows 10 "unified" approach correctly, Microsoft is trying to use the same underlying layer for all windows 10 versions (desktop, tablet, phone, ...) so that the app store etc can seamlessly be used on the different platforms.

Looking at the patch notes, I can only find a single patch notes entry for all versions combined. Does this mean that the underlying kernel code is shared among all these versions?

What does this mean in terms of malware and vulnerabilities, will a vulnerability/malware for windows 10 desktop also work on phones and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly much of the code of unified windows is common, but a lot will be machine specific such as code to control desktop CPUs is much different than code to control the processors in a smartphone. These newer systems starting with windows 10 make it much more difficult for viruses. That's one of the benefits of having a store, microsoft can scan all store items for virus code, and also the store creates a system where apps can develop a reputation, etc.
Microsoft copied a lot from Android for Windows 10, so on one hand it's a much more secure model, but yes, the fact there is common code on all these devices does mean a virus that successfully targets the common layer will potentially affect any type of device running win10.